# playframework 2.0 - exceeded max_user_connections on database evolutions?

Tags: mysql, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am looing any insight as to how I can configure my play 2.0 app to not use so many database connections on both database  evolutions and during runtime. I have asked this in the group and in IRC with no luck.

I am using cleardb ignite instance (max_user_connections = 10) with heroku...

Basically when I try to run database evolutions on my play 2.0 app I get:

```
! @6a2mjd7kg - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.db.evolutions.InvalidDatabaseRevision: Database 'default' needs evolution! [An SQL script need to be run on your database.]
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:424) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:410) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:410) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 9. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 8. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 7. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 6. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 5. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 4. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 3. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 2. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 1. Exception: null
 [error] application - 

! Internal server error, for request [GET /@evolutions/apply/default?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2F] ->

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User '52841e548f150d' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at       sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.  java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-  5.1.18.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
```

Then also I often will get the usual "Exceeded max_user_connections', this happens very frequently when not doing evolutions also.

I can also get this error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User '52841e548f150d' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 9. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 8. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 7. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 6. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 5. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 4. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 3. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 2. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 1. Exception: null
[error] application -
```

My application.conf looks like this, and I have tried many variations...

```
db.default=mysql 
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="mysql://usr:pass@db_url.com/db_name"
db.default.minSize=1
db.default.maxSize=2
```

Any guidance, suggessions, links, would be extremely helpful at this point...

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Looking into it...

Comment: I was able to make a simple app work against a local mysql database but could not get it working against ClearDB.  Can you file a Heroku support request?  Here is my test project:
https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars-java/tree/mysql

Answer (score 6):

Updated answer.

Here is a configuration that only uses 5 connections.

```
db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
```

# Connections will be `partitionCount x ConnectionsPerPartition`

Comment: Can you file a support request with Heroku?

Comment: @JamesWard I'm not so sure anymore it is heroku/clearDb but hwo you start the server start vs run I will update my answer.

Comment: This helped me. I was inconsistently getting connection exceptions when running tests locally against my Postgres database.