# playframework 2.0 - exceeded max_user_connections on database evolutions (with local postgres server)

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, postgresql-9.1

I am having the same exact issue as ([playframework 2.0 - exceeded max_user_connections on database evolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111885/playframework-2-0-exceeded-max-user-connections-on-database-evolutions)) only this time it is with a local postgres install. I have a sample application I threw up on hub @ http://git.io/CdEntA.

I attempt to run it locally, using

```
sbt stage
target/start -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -  Ddb.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test?user=myuser"
```

When I launch http://localhost:9000, all I see on the console is...

```
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null [info] play - Application started (Prod) [info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000... [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 9. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 8. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 7. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 6. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 5. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 4. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 3. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 2. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 1. Exception: null [error] c.j.b.PoolWatchThread - Error in trying to obtain a connection. Retrying in 1000ms org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
```

When I take a peek into the database, I see all connections are in fact used up by the process.

Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are not overriding the `db.default.user` config parameter so it's using the `sa` value.  Just comment out the following line in your `conf/application.conf` file:

```
db.default.user=sa
```

Once I did that and re-ran `sbt stage` then it worked fine for me.

Comment: +1 Had the same problem and commenting out the db.default.user solved it. Whereas I defined db.default.user as the db user actually have the rights to connect to the db -> db.default.user=play .Since I do not provide now a default user for the db connection, I do not understand why this solves the problem and why I actually can still login into my db without defining db.default.user. Can you give me an explanation why this is the source of the problem?

Comment: When you run locally the in-memory database doesn't need a user specified.  When you run on Heroku and you override the `db.default.url` then it pulls the username out of the url.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Try reducing the numbers of connections used by your play app.

Here is a configuration that only uses 5 connections.

```
db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
```

Basically the number of connections will be `partitionCount x ConnectionsPerPartition`