# play framework error in New I/O worker #1 when applying evolution script (JPA and Ebean version)

Tags: java, oracle, playframework, oracle10g, playframework-2.0

I try to set up the computer database sample on oracle 10g database but I get an error with the evolution script : 
after create the `play_evolution` table and `Company` and `Computer` table of the sample, play ask me to make the evolution script to put data into these database :
[image]

But when I try `Apply this script now!` I get this result :

```
2012-11-26 11:33:12,324 - [INFO] - from play in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1 
database [default] connected at jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.15:1521:orcl

2012-11-26 11:33:13,166 - [ERROR] - from application in New I/O  worker #1 


! @6celgd3g6 - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.db.evolutions.InvalidDatabaseRevision: Database 'default' needs evolution! [An SQL script need to be run on your database.]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:427) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:448) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:414) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:412) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:412) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:125) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at scala.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:277) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.dispatch.Future$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:195) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Future$$anon$3.run(Future.scala:194) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:94) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1381) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
```

and the application stay on the `needs evolution page` and the tables are empty in the DB so  apparently the script failed (I try it directly on SQL into oracle 10g and the script is working). Anyone can help me for to solved the problem ?

**EDIT 1: Here is my configuration file**

```
application.name=computer-database
application.secret="E27D^[_<Lpt0vjad]de;3/i;tx3gpRmG4Byof/3nahO/dIo9gbsMWut1w3xg[>9W"

db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.15:1521:orcl"
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.default.user=play
db.default.password=play

ebean.default="models.*"

"assets.cache./public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"="max-age=3600"

logger=ERROR

logger.play=INFO

logger.application=DEBUG
```

**EDIT 2:** I have tried with the JPA version of the sample : I get a similar error :
The same screen (`Database 'default' needs evolution!`) and when I click on `Apply this script now!` I get exactly the same stack error in log file

**EDIT 3 :** When I clean the DB, The application ask me to make the first evolution script (the structure of the tables and the data in the same time) so I accept to apply it : He create the tables on my DB but he doesn't insert the data and print the secrond screen where I'm blocked.... And at the begining, I got an error when the application try to create the play_evolution table. After some googled, I found that apparently the code for play_evolution is not working with oracle because of wrong type of fields.... So I created it manually

Comment: See if it's a [configuration problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10303333/315306)

Comment: it's not working (it's worse) because the application can't connect to my DB without user string :x. I edit my post to put the configuration file but I'm not sure it's a problem of connection string to my DB because the application access to the DB to check if the content of the database is ok. If my login or password or connection string were wrong, I get another error I think

Comment: does your database allows enough connections ?

Comment: I tried : `SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'sessions'` and the result is 170 so I think it's ok

Comment: nobody can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with `evolutionplugin=disabled` in `application.conf` so it's not a real solution. So I created a ticket [here](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/885-play-framework-and-oracle-10g-error-in-new-io-worker-1-when-applying-evolution-script-jpa-and-ebean-version)

Please read it to find the solution !

Answer (score 0):

It seems your configuration may be wrong, you sample says:

```
db.default.pass=play
```

When it should be:

```
db.default.password=play
```

See the [configuration](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SettingsJDBC) documentation.

Also, try to wipe the db completely, just in case.

**EDIT on comment:**

Seems that your db gets into an unstable position (evolution wise) for some reason, but the logs don't help. Are you running Play 2.0.4 (latest one)?

Given that's a sample project, I would solve this with a workaround:

- Disable evolutions by uncommenting `evolutionplugin=disabled` in `application.conf`
- Run the scripts manually on your database

At this stage the DB will have the data you need. If some connection/data type issue was the source of the errors you'll see it in the logs when running the application, otherwise everything should work.

You should also raise a ticket on [Lighthouse](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard) about the issue, as this seems a serious one.

Comment: Change for db.default.password and clean the DB = same result. I edited my post to insert more information to help us.

Comment: Yeah I use play 2.0.4. well it works with `evolutionplugin=disabled` but it's not a 'real solution' for me. I'll post a ticket on Lighthouse