# Play framework 1 - max_user_connections exceeded on mysql database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, heroku, c3p0, cloudcontrol

I'm trying to deploy an Play 1 app with a Mysql database on cloudcontrol (it's like Heroku). I always get the error:

```
User 'xy' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 2)
```

I've set the connections to 1 in the `application.conf`:

```
db.pool.minSize=1
db.pool.maxSize=1
```

But this didn't work.

I've found only a solution, for play 2: [playframework 2.0 - exceeded max_user_connections on database evolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111885/playframework-2-0-exceeded-max-user-connections-on-database-evolutions)

Comment: Just to make sure, are you connected to the database with an additional client (mysql)?
Also in the moment when you deploy a new set of containers are started, which means the number of connections are doubled for a short moment. With minSize and maxSize = 1, this should be fine.

Comment: No, there is just one client (one Web Container). I even tried to deploy the application with the non-free mysql addon which can handle 8 connections. But this also failed.

Comment: Did you tried it locally and checked how many connections where opened from you application? I tested in with a plain play-1.2.7 application and it directly open three connections to the mysql server.

Comment: thank you for the idea!

I used mytop to see the connections. My application uses 3 connection too. It seems that 3 connections are the minimum. If I set `db.pool.maxSize` to 1 or 2, there are also 3 connections. If I change it above 3, the numbers of connections will be raise.

I tried on cloudcontrol the 512mb mysql database with 8 connections,  but the error are still there, only the current value changes `User 'xy' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 8)`

Its really strange.